# If $y=\sum_i\frac{x_i}{\sigma_i^2}$ then is $\frac{\partial y}{\partial x_i}=\sum_i\frac{1}{\sigma_i^2}$ or is it equal to $\frac{1}{\sigma_i^2}$?

Tags: summation, partial-derivative, proof-explanation

I thought that the former is correct, but then I read this as part of certain proof:

[image]

Should the sigma be omitted on taking the partial derivative?

Comment: Since the $q_i$ are independent, then the summation disappears.

Comment: @Claude Thanks for your response. I don't quite understand how the $q_i$ being independent means that the $\sum$s disappear on taking the derivative. Or put in another way, why does differentiating get rid of the $\sum$s? Could you please elaborate a bit more on this by making an answer perhaps? Thanks.

Comment: Wehn you compute the deivative with respect to $q_1$, all other $q_i$'s are constants. Then,  the summation disappears.

Comment: @Claude Thank you, makes sense now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me give an example and hopefully things clear up:

$$f=x+2y$$

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=1$$
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=2$$

Comment: Thanks for your time, I understand now.

Comment: Is there any chance you could help me with [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1582971/tricky-proof-that-the-weighted-average-is-a-better-estimate-than-the-un-weighted)? A user has already posted a great answer but I lack the level to understand it. You have given a great intuitive answer with this one; I was wondering if you could try to do the same again with the question linked in this comment?