# How to compute double summations where the two summands are not independent?

Tags: summation, intuition

### Edit:

From the vote counts I see that people want this question closed as it seems unclear what I was asking, so I have tried to word it a bit better to avoid closure. I hope this helps, please comment if it is still unclear. Thank you.

---

If $$\sum_{i,j}a_{i,j}=\sum_i^N\sum_j^N a_{i,j},$$
then
$$\sum_{i,j\ne i} a_{i,j}=\sum_i^N\sum_{j:j\ne i}^N a_{i,j} =
\color{red}{\sum_i^N\left(\sum_{j=1}^{i-1} a_{i,j} + \sum_{j=i+1}^{N} a_{i,j}\right)}=\sum_i^N\left(\sum_{j=1}^{i-1} a_{i,j} + \color{blue}{a_{i,i}}+ \sum_{j=i+1}^{N} a_{i,j}\right)$$

Could someone please explain why the $\color{blue}{\mathrm{blue}}$ term in the summand is present?

Comment: The blue term _isn't_ present.  Either the answer was changed, or you're confusing the answer with a different sum in the comments.

Comment: @Slade Did you read all the comments in [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1582971/tricky-proof-that-the-weighted-average-is-a-better-estimate-than-the-un-weighted)?

Comment: Yes, of course.  Michael wrote the following identity: $\sum_{i=1}^N\sum_{j=1}^N a_{i,j} = \sum_{i=1}^N (\sum_{j=1}^{i-1} a_{i,j} + a_{i,i} + \sum_{j=i+1}^N a_{i,j})$, which is true but different from the one in his post.  You seem to have decided that the two should be equal for some reason.

Comment: Thanks @Slade makes sense now; I see my mistake, but I still don't how  he has split the sum into $\sum_i^N\left(\sum_{j=1}^{i-1} a_{i,j} + \sum_{j=i+1}^{N} a_{i,j}\right)$ where the regions are $j=i-1$ and $j=i+1$ but what about $j=i$? I know this is really simple to you but it ain't clear to me :(

Comment: I am confused by your confusion.  Your question is asking why there is an $a_{i,i}$ term, which there isn't, but when I say there is no such term you say you're confused that there isn't one.  There are two sums, $\sum_{i,j}$ and $\sum_{i,j\neq i}$.  The former has terms of the form $a_{i,i}$, and the latter, by definition, doesn't.

Comment: Put differently, we skip $j=i$ precisely because the sum says $j\neq i$!

Comment: I feel I owe you some rep @Slade as your efforts should not go unrewarded. How about making an answer to this question elaborating on what you explained to me in these comments? Maybe, pushing my luck but would you consider answering the [original post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1582971/tricky-proof-that-the-weighted-average-is-a-better-estimate-than-the-un-weighted)? Michael gave a great answer, but it is sadly beyond my level. If you can explain it simpler then you're a winner :).

Comment: If you have trouble manipulating double summations one trick is to just think of a double summation as a way of adding all the elements of a matrix up. When you sum $a_{ij}$ over two indices with the condition that $i \ne j $ you are adding up all of the elements in a matrix other than those on the diagonal. I find this always helps me.

Comment: Don't worry about my reputation points, worry about learning double summations. ;)

Comment: @Slade That was my intention, by asking for your help